# Is it possible to have Facebook sharer use multiple images?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We use OGP for our site, and we have a large image (1.91:1 format) and a small image (quadratic).

How do we get Facebook to use the quadratic version for chat and comments, and the large version for shares etc.?

Comment: You can't. Facebook will pick one and use that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you 100% sure? Do you know how Facebook picks the images?